# Is there a way to use a test class to verify a dunder method is working properly?

Tags: python, unit-testing

I am writing a couple of classes to make a card game (in Python). In one of the classes, I redefine `__gt__` to take in the values passed to it and validate which card is higher. I have to write a test class for this and was not sure if you have to test this method usually or how to properly test it. The `__gt__` has `self, p2` as parameters being passed if that helps at all.

Comment: Create two cards, [assert on the comparison](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertGreater)?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.